# Minecraft 1.8.9 crashing in ubuntu

Tags: java, minecraft

here is the log

java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.10, mixed mode, sharing)

````
Preparing to launch minecraft client for 1.8.9
17:50:34.903
Prepared asset index
17:50:34.909
Have 756 total files to check or download
17:50:34.909
Waiting for 756 futures
17:50:35.196
Checking installations.
17:50:35.197
Minecraft client 1.8.9 is ready to start.
17:50:35.197
Starting!
17:50:35.197
Nothing to download!
17:50:35.197
Extracting 2 files!
17:50:35.206
Using default game log configuration client-1.7.xml (outputs XML)
17:50:35.206
Installing versions!
17:50:36.181
Setting user: jontyMS
17:50:36.186
(Session ID is token:#####################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################)
17:50:37.167
Skipping bad option: key_key.attack:key.mouse.left
17:50:37.167
Skipping bad option: key_key.use:key.mouse.right
17:50:37.168
Skipping bad option: key_key.forward:key.keyboard.w
17:50:37.168
Skipping bad option: key_key.left:key.keyboard.a ```
````

Comment: multi mc functions properly

Comment: what version of ubuntu and what version of openjdk "java -version"

Comment: DId you get it working?